# Why the differential equations have a wave behavior?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

The differential equation for string:

$$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \tag{1}$$

I have inital condition:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}20x, & 0\le x<0.2 \\ -(20x-1)/9,& 0.2\le x \le 1   \end{cases} \tag{2}$$

The output:
[inital condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6x4X.png)

The finite difference version:

$$U^t_{i} = {2(1-l)}U^{t-1}_{i}+l(U^{t-1}_{i-1}+U^{t-1}_{i+1})-U^{t-2}_{i} \tag{3}$$

where $l=0.25$

The output with interpolation:

[several time steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEPSY.png)

And full video:
[String vibration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ezl8ICXpTM)

All works fine, but I don't understand how $(3)$ can give such result, I don't see $sin$ or $cos$, or other periodical function in formulas $(1)$ and $(3)$, so why this finite difference equation or string difference equation gives periodical process?

Comment: Use instead the canonical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula

Comment: @Jonas how it can help me?

Comment: Solve your equation using this solution (using whatever for the derivative, that you don't have at time $0$) and check that it provides a wave behavior (really not the best to call it "oscillatory").

Comment: @Jonas thanks, I will try to figure out it.